# What is the meaning of "The shame of [something]"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, attachment-ambiguity

I didn't find the meaning of **The shame of [something]** in my search on the internet and that's why I can't conclude its meaning precisely. I want to use **The shame of his book** for some text in this specific structure as it is grammatically valid, but I think it can mean two meanings.

First possible meaning which I want to convey:

> the shame that is attached to his book.
>   (*his book has been harmed*)

Second possible meaning:

> the shame that is caused by his book.
>   (*his book is the one that harms*)

Could it mean them both or one more than the other?

Comment: I cannot believe you can't look that up in a bilingual dictionary and then a monolingual one.  The shame of [some situation].

Comment: Of course, Lambie, I did that. The translation to my native language didn't really help as it resulted in a phrase that would not be easily understood or even absorbed as a valid phrase in Arabic, exactly as its case in English **to me**. As for the search, each time I had substituted a word in [somthing], and once I didn't, the idiom with its definition appeared (I did that after reading your comment), but I have to say that it wasn't of much help. Thanks to @James' very useful answer, I now understand it well. And thank you for the *feedback*, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom "The shame of it" is used when referring to some act that brings shame on the speaker or the subject of conversation.

> My daughter is marrying a Motorbike gang member. Oh the shame of it! (it refers to "marrying")

The expression is sometimes used with abstract nouns, referring to something that causes shame:

> The shame of poverty prevents many from seeking help.

Or something that is shamed

> Abuse is the shame of the Catholic church.

It would not be common to use "the shame of" with a concrete noun, but if you did the meaning would depend on context and whether you are speaking of something that can be shamed.  In the case of a book, you can't cause a book to be shamed, because it isn't a person or an organisation.  So the book must be causing shame.

> The shame of the book attaches to the author, the publisher and every reader.

However, this is an unusual and highly marked use of the expression. I wouldn't use this expression on its own, but only in an essay on the nature of shame (for example)